# Layout shrinks when making dialog title free

Tags: dialog

I am using a custom dialog and it works fine when I use it with a title but when I apply the following code to remove the title, the dialog box seems to be shrinked:

```
alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Please add tag for the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Set style in your onCreate()this helps to have not shrunk dialog without title.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
}
```

Comment: @ Virat Paur I cannot understand what you are trying to say can you please explain it a little

Comment: Set this code in OnCreate() method after your dialog is not shrunk